# Handle the actions after clicking Save button for standard new/edit record modal

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I have a custom lwc component, with a new button. I am using **NavigationMixin** to leverage the standard new record creation form on pressing the New button on the custom component. Is there a way where I can control the actions to be performed after I click save on the standard form.
Here is sample code used to navigate to the New record creation form. I want to control the actions to be performed after I click save.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__objectPage',
        attributes: {
            objectApiName: this.items.relatedObjectApiName,
            actionName: "new"
        },
        state: {
            nooverride: '1',
            defaultFieldValues: this.items.relatedFieldApiName+"="+this.recordId,
            recordTypeId: recTypeId
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you come up with any solution to this?